# How to index two columns automatically in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

I have a table in sql having two fields 'JOB_NUMBER' 'SRno', the relation between the two is such that  each job number has many SRNO starting from 1,2,3 and so on,every new Job number has to have a SR no starting form 1,

so my ideal table should some what look like this:

```
JOB_NUMBER    SRno
   1            1
   1            2 
   1            3
   2            1
   2            2
   3            1 and so on.......
```

What I want to do is to achive this indexing in sql itself ,can I do this ,is so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is another column on the table that is something like a timestamp (e.g. time submitted), then you can do something like:

```
select job_number, 
   row_number() over (partition by job_number order by time_submitted asc) as SRno
from tbl
```

You could make that into a view and you're good to go. Keep in mind that this will be sensitive to data modifications (i.e. if someone inserts a row between two other rows, the rows after the inserted one will be "renumbered"). Also keep in mind that this won't store the SRno on the table; it has to be calculated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You mean auto-numbering (indexing is something different in DBMS's). It can be achieved using a trigger. But that's DBMS-specific issue. Check if your database supports triggers.

Comment: I am using sql server 2005,I only know the basics of sql ,so is it possilbe to auto number like this in sql 2005

Comment: Wikipedia says: "Microsoft SQL Server supports triggers either after or instead of an insert, update or delete operation. They can be set on tables and views". So probably yes, you can write a trigger function to pick a value for newly inserted row. But I'm no expert on MS SQL Server and cannot give you any details on that.

Comment: using sequence you can create two column auto increment

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this..

```
select JOB_NUMBER,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by JOB_NUMBER order by JOB_NUMBER) 
as SRno from table_jobs
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that that's going to be non-deterministic. That is, within a given partition in your ranking function, all rows are considered equal. So the server is welcome to order them however it wants.

Comment: @BenThul: partially agree with you.. :) within partition the job_number is same, so the order doesn't matter there, as the question says he wants sequence number for same set of job_number. I agree that in select statement, the order might be different